# capacitive action in transmission lines

Tags: capacitor

When two conductors separated by dielectric it acts as a capacitor,in my case tranmission lines are current carrying conductors and they are separated by dielectric material(air)and it acts as capacitor.suppose it carrying 4ookv(line) then according to modified amperes law differential current will flow through air(dielectric medium) in form of electrical flux but we are not getting shock why?if it is dangerous in what cases?

Answer (score 1):

It is dangerous.

High voltage power lines usually separated 3m minimum. The air (even humid) it is a good insulator keeping the capacitance in very-very low values. Current it is proportion of capacitance and RMS voltage between conductors

I=2πfVrmsC

In case of a medium size bird –a sphere of 20cm and consequently capacitance of around 10pF placed between the lines/capacitor-, the current will be close to 1mA.

For humans (sphere 1m) and for 400kV the current may be reach the dangerous 10mA. In 100kV lines the hazard risk is much less. You can search the relevant safety standards dealing on how to aproache HVl ines autorized and non-authorized people.

All above considered a capacitor with the second shell at 0 potential. However HV power lines it is delta source i.e without any common conductor.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP saw powerline workers in some poorer country at work. In the richer ones, they wear chainmail suits so the intense EM-field induced currents discharge through that rather than the workers' bodies. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HFZVBmP8uVY